# Rails can't save value from radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, radio-button, simple-form

I have this line in a form made with Simple Form:

```
 <fieldset>
    <legend>Any acessory?</legend>
      <li><%= f.input :has_acessory, label: false, collection: ["0","1"], as: :radio_buttons, input_html:{ name: 'has_acessory'} %></li>
</fieldset>
```

and Simple  Form generates this code:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Any Acessory?</legend>
      <li><div class="input radio_buttons optional lending_has_acessory"><label class="radio"><input checked="checked" class="radio_buttons optional" id="lending_has_acessory_0" name="has_acessory" type="radio" value="0" />0</label><label class="radio"><input class="radio_buttons optional" id="lending_has_acessory_1" name="has_acessory" type="radio" value="1" />1</label></div></li>
</fieldset>
```

I'm using SQLite3, Where there's a table called lendings with an Integer column called has_acessory and it's default value is: 0

In Lending model:

```
class Lending < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :devolution_date, :lending_date, :situation, :description,:has_acessory, :person_id, :equipment_id
#Associations
belongs_to :equipment
belongs_to :person
```

end

But it doesn't matter which value that I choose in the radio buttons,I always get "0" (the default value)in the has_acessory column.I already checked the params, and I can find "has_acessory" =>"0" or "1".

For me this part is working pretty well, but why can't it be saved in the has_acessory column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to let rails do more of the work for you.

Please try just `<%= f.input :has_acessory %>` and see what that gives you.

Having all this `<%= f.input :has_acessory, label: false, collection: ["0","1"], as: :radio_buttons, input_html:{ name: 'has_acessory'} %>` makes it hard to debug.

Please look at the migration/database and make sure that the field is boolean.  If it is, rails will figure out all the right options for you.

Also - you say that the field has a default - but I don't see that in the model.  Did you just omit that line in the model?  Is it in both the rails model and the database?

Comment: When I tried just <%= f.input :has_acessory %>, I could find out that my problem was in input_html:{ name: 'has_acessory'}.When I deleted this instruction, simple form generated name="lending[has_acessory]" and it worked. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Add this line into the controller method

```
params[:has_acessory] = params[:has_acessory].to_i
```